# FriendlyId triggers BEFORE model validations. How do I get around this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, friendly-id

Ideally i want urls that look like:

/users/john-s

/users/foo-b

/users/brad-p

I have a user model that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged

  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true

  # "John Smith" becomes "John S."
  def name
    "#{self.first_name.capitalize} #{self.last_name[0].capitalize}."
  end
end
```

The bad behavior is best explained with this console output:

```
[15] pry(main)> User.new(first_name: nil, last_name: nil).save!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass
```

**The Issue (finally! :) )**

It appears what happens is that FriendlyId is called BEFORE my validations for `first_name` and `last_name` are triggered.  This results in the `name` method pooping when capitalize is called on a nil value.

What can I do so that my validations are triggered before FriendlyId is called?  And actually taking it a bit further... Why is FriendlyId involved at all prior to any validity being established?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

It is invoked because the slug is generated prior to validation on save:

https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id/issues/280

I am not quite sure what it would take to monkeypatch it.

Comment: Any suggestions for an alternative approach that might not require monkeypatching?

Comment: I would probably redefine `name` slightly and only return a valid name when first and last are set. Thanks to validation this should only occur before a valid slug is needed.

Comment: Could anyone provide me with how to monkeypatch this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to go is to set the user name in a before_validation on create that has is prepended to the friendly_id's own before_validation callback of setting the slug:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged

  # Make sure to prepend it so that it runs before Friendly_id's own callback
  # http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
  before_validation :set_name, on: :create, prepend: true

  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true

  # To control when new slugs should be generated
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record? || first_name_changed? || last_name_changed?
  end

  private

  def set_name
    "#{self.first_name.capitalize} #{self.last_name[0].capitalize}."
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If someone is using :history, I think it might be best to omit the 'on: :create'. So the line that reads 'before_validation :set_name, on: :create, prepend: true' should be: 'before_validation :set_name, prepend: true'.

Answer (score 1):

The way I wound up fixing mine was like this:

```
  def name
    "#{self.first_name.capitalize} #{self.last_name[0].capitalize}." if first_name.present? && last_name[0].present?
  end
```

Comment: Bro...this just saved me. Thanks!